# Pygame shooting in all directions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to make a space invaders/asteroids game where you can shoot in all directions using pygame. Currently, I can move my ship in all directions and shoot in all directions, but as soon as I change directions my bullets that were previously fired will stop moving/move in the direction that the ship is going. Thank you in advance.

```
import pygame
import random
# intialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# dimensions of the pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

# Caption and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Saving Earth")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# images
earth_image = pygame.image.load('earth.png')

fly_up = pygame.image.load('spaceshipU.png')

fly_down = pygame.image.load('spaceshipD.png')

fly_left = pygame.image.load('spaceshipL.png')

fly_right = pygame.image.load('spaceshipR.png')

background = pygame.image.load('space.jpg')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Player class
class player(object):
    def __init__(self, player_x, player_y, width, height):
        self.player_x = player_x
        self.player_y = player_y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.speed = 4
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.up = True
        self.down = False

    # draws the ship to screen
    def draw(self, screen):

        if self.left:
            screen.blit(fly_left, (self.player_x,self.player_y))

        elif self.right:
            screen.blit(fly_right, (self.player_x,self.player_y))

        elif self.up:
            screen.blit(fly_up, (self.player_x,self.player_y))

        elif self.down:
            screen.blit(fly_down, (self.player_x,self.player_y))

        else:
            screen.blit(fly_up, (self.player_x,self.player_y))


class Bullet(object):
    def __init__(self, bullet_x, bullet_y, radius, color):
        self.bullet_x = bullet_x
        self.bullet_y = bullet_y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 6
        self.vertfacing = 1
        self.hortfacing = 1

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.bullet_x,self.bullet_y), self.radius)


# redraws game screen
def redraw_game_screen():
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(earth_image, (350, 230))
    ship.draw(screen)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

#Game Loop
ship = player(300, 300, 32, 32)
bullets = []
vertfacing = -1
hortfacing = 1
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.bullet_x < 800 and bullet.bullet_x > 0 and bullet.bullet_y < 600 and bullet.bullet_y > 0 :
            if hortfacing == -1 and ship.left:
                bullet.bullet_x -= bullet.speed
            elif hortfacing == 1 and ship.right:
                bullet.bullet_x += bullet.speed
            elif vertfacing == 1 and ship.down:
                bullet.bullet_y += bullet.speed
            elif vertfacing == -1 and ship.up:
                bullet.bullet_y -= bullet.speed
        else:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

    #key commands
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        if ship.left:
            hortfacing = -1
        elif ship.right:
            hortfacing = 1
        elif ship.up:
            vertfacing = -1
        elif ship.down:
            vertfacing = 1

        if len(bullets) < 100:
            bullets.append(Bullet(round(ship.player_x + ship.width //2), round(ship.player_y + ship.height//2), 6, (255,165,0)))


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and ship.player_x > ship.speed:
        ship.player_x -= ship.speed
        ship.left = True
        ship.right = False
        ship.up = False
        ship.down = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and ship.player_x < 800 - ship.speed - ship.width:
        ship.player_x += ship.speed
        ship.right = True
        ship.left = False
        ship.up = False
        ship.down = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and ship.player_y > ship.speed:
        ship.player_y -= ship.speed
        ship.up = True
        ship.down = False
        ship.left = False
        ship.right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and ship.player_y < 600 - ship.height - ship.speed:
        ship.player_y += ship.speed
        ship.down = True
        ship.up = False
        ship.left = False
        ship.right = False

    redraw_game_screen()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You are using the ship's direction to update the bullet position. You need to change that.

Comment: Bullets should not be conditionally updated based on the ships position, when you create a bullet set it horizontal and vertical direction and then when you redraw the bullet use those as the conditions for update and not the ship

Answer (score 2):

You have to se the attributes `vertfacing` and `hortfacing` in the class `Bullet`:

```py
class Bullet(object):
    def __init__(self, bullet_x, bullet_y, radius, color, vertfacing, hortfacing):
        self.bullet_x = bullet_x
        self.bullet_y = bullet_y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 6
        self.vertfacing = vertfacing
        self.hortfacing = hortfacing

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.bullet_x,self.bullet_y), self.radius)
```

Pass the attributes to the constructor when a `Bullet` spawns:

```py
if len(bullets) < 100:
    bullet = Bullet(round(ship.player_x + ship.width //2), 
                    round(ship.player_y + ship.height//2), 6, (255,165,0),
                    vertfacing, hortfacing)
    bullets.append(bullet)
```

Use the attributes of bullet (`bullet.hortfacing`, `bullet.vertfacing`) when you calculate the new position.

Add a method to the class `Bullet` that moves it:

```py
class Bullet(object):

    # [...]

    def move(self):
        if self.hortfacing == -1:
            self.bullet_x -= self.speed
        elif self.hortfacing == 1:
            self.bullet_x += self.speed
        elif self.vertfacing == 1:
            self.bullet_y += self.speed
        elif self.vertfacing == -1:
            self.bullet_y -= self.speed
```

Call the method for each bullet:

```py
for bullet in bullets:
    if bullet.bullet_x < 800 and bullet.bullet_x > 0 and bullet.bullet_y < 600 and bullet.bullet_y > 0 :
        bullet.move()
    else:
        bullets.remove(bullet)
```